# Can SAS still read or create the combination of {.dat fixed-column ascii data file, .sas syntax file}, or is it obsolete?

Tags: r, sas

In the past I have used the excellent SAScii package in R to read in this type of data: {.dat fixed-column data file + the corresponding .sas "syntax" file}.  I want to be quite precise about that because there is no end of ambiguity surrounding phrases like "SAS file".  These .dat files contain only integers, and the .sas files specify both the way to parse the columns *and* the way the integers represent the values in the actual data (this feature is sometimes called the "codebook".)  I have found very good data in that format (i.e. in the form of the pair of files {.dat, .sas}) from places like Minnesota Population Center's IPUMS https://usa.ipums.org/usa/, and built up a lot of tools to analyze it using R and SAScii.

Now I have access to SAS itself, and but would still like to re-use some of my tools and techniques.  However I can find no reference in SAS to data like that {fixed-column data in .dat, syntax file in .sas}.  Has that format been entirely superseded within SAS (perhaps by the SAS7BDAT format)?  Or perhaps the {.dat,.sas} format was *never* used *within* SAS??  The reason I ask is, now that I have access to SAS and so much data in SAS7BDAT format, I would like to be able to export some of it in {.dat, .sas} format for use with my own tools.

Thanks very much, and cheers - Ed

Comment: I'm not familiar with the format you're describing, but can't you just export from SAS to csv using `PROC EXPORT` and then read the csvs into your other tools?

Comment: I don't think you would normally keep data that way, but it sounds like a way to export or import data.  SPSS for example will happily make that, R probably also will.  `.sas` is a syntax file, so any program you wrote would have that extension.  It's not "obsolete" per se, it's just not the way it's kept internally usually.  I don't know that SAS would normally _produce_ this, though, so I don't know if you can get it out of SAS without writing it yourself.  SPSS or something else would usually be creating this (for the purpose of importing into SAS).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something built into SAS.  You could, however, write such a program pretty easily.

First off, Chris Hemidinger has written something that basically does this (it creates datalines, not .dat file, but that shouldn't be too hard to modify if you know .NET and/or to modify the R module to accept). That is discussed and available [here](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2013/01/21/turn-your-data-set-into-a-data-step-program/).  The title of the post is "Turn your data set into a data step program".  This is roughly equivalent to the SQL Server task that creates "Create Table" code out of a table.  This would only work in Enterprise Guide, although you should be able to do roughly the same thing in a standalone .NET program.

Second, you can easily write something like this in Base SAS.  Creating the datalines is easy, numerous ways to write out to a file.

For a CSV, for example, you can do this.

```
ods csv file="c:\temp\mydata.csv";
proc print data=mydata;
run;
ods csv close;
```

If you're going to write a flat file, you might as well make the input/output .sas first - after all it can be almost the same code.  You can query dictionary.columns to generate the code, both the input and output code.  Create a table with the variable names, lengths, and formats for each variable, then process it in a data step advancing the `start` variable by the length of each variable (so it moves to the next position after the last one finished).  If you need formats for your R project, then `proc format cntlout=<datasetname>` will generate a dataset that contains those formatted value translations, and you can write that out in whatever format you need as well.